# onActivityResult does not call and Fragment close itself from image picker Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi I know there is so much question related to this but still i can not find right way :(

I read this link [onActivityResult is not being called in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment/#24303360) but i can not find the solution.

```
              Intent intent = new Intent();
              intent.setType("image/*");
              intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
              startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""),
                                    PICK_IMAGE);


        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && data.getData() != null) {
                        imagePath = getAbsolutePath(data.getData());

                        imageLoader.loadImage("file://" + imagePath,
                                new ImageLoadingListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri,
                                            View view) {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri,
                                            View view, FailReason failReason) {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri,
                                            View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                                        height = loadedImage.getHeight();
                                        width = loadedImage.getWidth();
                                        if (Utils
                                                .validateImageSize(height, width,
                                                        getActivity(),
                                                        "Image size must be in 480 (width) & 800 (height)    with PNG or JPG format"))
                                            imageLoader.displayImage("file://"
                                                    + imagePath, ivSubmitImgWord,
                                                    options);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri,
                                            View view) {
                                    }
                                });

                    }
                }

            }
```

when i choose image from gallery sometimes onActivityResult is not call and Fragment is close.please anybody can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: If your fragment is closing, I can only assume your getting an Exception of some kind, could you check and post the results of your Logcat? That would go a long way in helping us to determine what is wrong.

Comment: I am not getting any kind of Exception.when i choose image from gallery it's simply close the fragment.

Comment: Did you find a solution for your issue in the end?

Comment: No i didn't get solution

Comment: What is your value for `PICK_IMAGE` try to use a value less than 100 for `PICK_IMAGE`

Comment: Try to check whether your Fragment is detach from activity or not

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` in your fragment and override

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {}
```

Comment: Have same issue !

Answer (score 0):

check if you have `noHistory=true` set on your manifest for the activity. This will not call onActivityResult